# Unmount drives fails

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

Symptoms significantly different from [Unable to unmount drive!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55688/unable-to-unmount-drive)

I have six external volumes.  An 8TB drive is partitioned into **5TB** and **3TB**.  There are also four full drives named **PB**, **W5TB**, **4TB**, and **Untitled**.

All are APFS on a 2019 Intel MacBook Pro with the latest O.S.  5TB, W5TB, and 4TB are Time Machine backups.  Neither Cmd-E nor the eject icon nor `diskutil eject` will remove the Volume icon for **PB** and **3TB** from Finder.  It works as expected for all the others.  No diagnostic message appears.  **Sometimes**, the contents disappear, i.e., it looks like an empty volume in Finder, but sometimes the contents still show.  `df` will still show /Volumes/{PB,3TB}.

The Disk Utility GUI won't eject them either.  First Aid says they have no errors.

None of them are listed in /etc/fstab

Any advice on diagnosis or on fixing would be welcome.

Comment: Do you have a Finder window open that’s located on the mount point or are you currently in a working directory (Terminal). Type `pwd` and if the path shows you’re in that mount point, it won’t eject.

Comment: Neither.  When it's not in use, the 'no diagnostic' behavior happens.  And it's only those two volumes.  Other volumes, if open in Finder, clicking the eject works and closes the Finder window without complaint.  If in use by Terminal, I get a pop-up saying the volume is in use.

Comment: If you’re getting a message that it’s in use, it’s in use. You could have a file open, a folder, or even just be in the directory

Comment: Try killing "mdworker" and other "md_____" things—these are parts of Spotlight and usually why I cannot eject drives. You could also open Settings (née System Preferences) and add the drives to the Privacy section so Spotlight stops doing stuff with the drives permanently.

Comment: Hmmm, Spotlight might well be the cause.  Even so, silently ignoring dismount is certainly a design error.  Two remote (SSHFS) mounts get a pop-up offering to "Force Eject" when they are (incorrectly) labeled as being in use.  But nothing for these two.